# I want to know the number of times the same image has been added to the ListBox of images

Tags: wpf, image, c#-3.0, listbox

I have a ListBox of images. I want to know the  number of times the same image has been added to that ListBox. Any solutions?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to check that the image itself, regardless of the file name, is not repeated then generate an MD5 checksum for the image data and store that.

If you want to make sure that the two are always linked then either tag it onto the end of the file or create a class which holds the image and the checksum together.

The MD5 check can be used to differentiate any data file, even different versions of the same file if the content is in anyway different.

Comment: I dont know about MD5.can u plz give the source code if u with u

Comment: You need to use the MD5 class. It's in namespace System.Security.Cryptography

Possible code (note that you can have the imageFile as a byte array or as a data stream):

MD5 md5 = new MD5CryptoServiceProvider();

byte[] md5Checksum = md5.ComputeHash(imageFileData);